# I need help understanding the answer of combinatorics problem

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

The problem says

> there is a deck of 52 cards. There is 13 different cards (each one has a number),and each one has it's own color, there is 4 colors (4 * 13 = 52). On how many ways can you find 2 different cards?

I tried to solve it like this: 
https://imgur.com/a/3Gs0GxN?fbclid=IwAR2Lk7yKKxBR8d9I-lBPXMVxCnYjcv0c0JfTGe0KkkA87r34eyOTIuUGH0w

What I don't understand is why would the answer be (13 ncr 2) * 4 * 4 (why *4?)?

I know that for every column there will be (13 ncr 2) different combinations, and there is 4 columns so that is (13 ncr 2) * 4.
Now that would probably be a good solution if the task said, 'On how many ways can we find two different cards with the same color'. But I don't know why in the end we again multiplied with 4?

Comment: What I don't understand is why it's simply not $\binom{52}{2}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $13$ different ranks (numbers) and you must choose two different ranks.

This is where the $\binom{13}{2}$ comes from.

You must also choose one of $4$ colors for each of the chosen ranks.

This is where the $\times4\times4$ comes from.

Comment: 'You must also choose one of 4 colors for each of the chosen ranks.' Ok that is why I must multiply with 4 , but why I must again multiply with 4?

Comment: @Petar 5 You have $2$ cards with $4$ choices. The amount of color-combinations is $4\cdot4=4^2$.

Comment: @Petar: $\times 4$ for the first card, and $\times 4$ again for the second card.